# Wire:model Not showing Selected value from Array Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have problem when i tried to Update/Change pivot table on Many to Many relationship on laravel. i have retrieved data from pivot and want to show it as selected in select input but its seem not working.
Here the table:
[many to many table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqRil.jpg)

Officer Model scope return specific title based on category:

```
public function scopeFilterByCategory(Builder $query, $type = 'spv')
{
    return $query->select('id', 'name', 'title_id')->with('title')
        ->whereHas('title', function (Builder $query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('category', '=', $type); })->get();
}
```

Project livewire component:

```
class DataProject extends Component
{
    //Person in Charge
    public $pic = [];

    public Project $project;
    //rest of codes

    public function save()
    {
        $this->project->save();
        $data_pic = Arr::flatten($this->pic);
        $this->project->officers()->attach($data_pic);
    }

    public function showUpdateModal(Project $project)
    {
        if ($this->project->isNot($project)) $this->project = $project;
        //Retrieve officers assigned to project
        foreach ($project->officers as $person) {
            $this->pic[] = $person->id;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
            return view('livewire.project.data-project', [
                'dataProject' => $this->rows,
                'spv' => Officer::filterByCategory() //scope func
                'manager' => Officer::filterByCategory('mgr')
            ]);
    }
}
```

Blade view form taken from update/edit modal:

```
<select wire:model="pic.0" class="custom-select">
    @foreach ($spv as $person)
    <option value="{{ $person->id }}">{{ $person->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select wire:model="pic.1" class="custom-select">
    @foreach ($manager as $mgr)
    <option value="{{ $mgr->id }}">{{ $mgr->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

lets assume we select officer id 5 on wire:model="pic.0",and oficcer_id 1 on wire:model="pic.1". And resulting:

```
$pic = array[
    0 => 5,
    1 => 1,
];
```

when i save model and attach pic[] property to project_officer table, all good and saved. the problem come when im try to Update/change assigned officer, my SELECT input not showing selected officer from PIC[] property(contains data from query) even im using Wire:model to bind the property. select input only select default opt (first line). Its even worse when i have more officer list. My expect is when PIC[] property filled with data from query, SELECT input select the value from PIC[], and showing as selected. any workaround to make value from PIC shown as selected in form?